# Obtaining RSSI from Scan Request / Scan Reply packets

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I'm new to android development and I'm writing a APP as proof of concept for a research project using the BLE Google API. I have two android phones, one of which is advertising some beacon X that carries a scan response Y, while the second phone is scanning for advertisements. I would like to access the **RSSI values** corresponding to the **ScanRequest and ScanReply** packets that follow the advertisement.

During device to device communication, when the overwritten `onScanCallback` method is called on the second phone, I can only obtain a single RSSI value by calling `result.getRssi()` on the passed ScanResult. Furthermore, as expected, the corresponding ScanRecord provides two ServiceUuids by calling the `record.getServiceUuids`, where the first UUID corresponds to the advertisement itself, and the second one to the programmed scan reply.

Until now I haven't found any public methods to recover the **RSSI of the ScanReply**, is there some other way of accessing this second RSSI? And the same applies to the **RSSI of the ScanRequest** that is automatically sent by the listening device, is there a way of recovering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSSI in the scan callback already corresponds to the RSSI in the scan response packet, not the advertising packet. Android's Bluetooth stack throws away the RSSI value for the first packet. Why do you need it anyway? It should be more or less the same as the first packet since both packets are sent within such a short interval.

You can't get RSSI for a scan request. This info is not sent from controller to host if you read the HCI standard. Even if the Bluetooth stack would listen to "LE Scan Request Received event", that event doesn't include RSSI.

Comment: Many peripherals gauge and return RSSI of incoming scan response requests.